# How do i compare the strings in the if statement?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my code

```
public void refreshSmsInbox() {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    arrayAdapter.clear();
        do {
            if (smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress).toString()=="6641234567") {

                String str = "SMS From:" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) +
                        "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
                arrayAdapter.add(str);
            }
            else {
                String str = "It doesnt work";
                arrayAdapter.add(str);
            }
            Log.d("Phone Number",smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress));
        } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());

}
```

I want to make a app that pop up when a certain phone number send you a sms I already make that the app read the sms but when i try to make the app show the messages from only certain number it doesnt enter but i dont know why i make a debug resaearh from `smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress).toString()` and it give me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zsvt.png)  and the result is the same from my condition

also [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBiQS.png) is the view from my aplication

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubjAR.png) is the view when i removed the if statement

it is very weird for my There is an explination for this? because i can see that the comparasion i made in the if statement is the same that the output in the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare string values using `equals` and not `==`.

Change `smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress).toString()=="6641234567"` to `smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress).equals("6641234567")`, then it should register that it works.

Comment: Do you have a sugestion how can i pop up the app when that number is show

Answer (score 0):

To compare strings you need to use `equals`, `==` will not work.

Also make sure you are writing the **exact** text you need to compare to, because a space is also considered a character and can make the comparison not work.

So, change ...`toString()=="6641234567"` to ...`toString().equals("6641234567")`